# Error when using write_as_csv() in rtweet package

Tags: r, rtweet

When I use the write_as_csv() from the rtweet package, I get the following error:

```
   Twitterstorians_hashtag <- search_tweets(
                                q="#Twitterstorians",
                                n = 100,
                                type = "recent",
                                include_rts = TRUE,
                                parse = TRUE,

                               )

      save_as_csv(Twitterstorians_hashtag, "Twitterstorians_hashtag.csv", prepend_ids         
      = TRUE, na = "", fileEncoding = "UTF-8")

      Error in utils::write.table(x, file_name, row.names = FALSE, na = na,  : 
      unimplemented type 'list' in 'EncodeElement'
      In addition: Warning message:
      In flatten(x) : data frame still contains recursive columns!
```

If I try to use flatten(), I get the following error:

```
      Error in flatten_int(x) : Not compatible with STRSXP: [type=list].
```

I'm not sure how to fix these errors?  Any suggestions would be much appreciated

Comment: Perhaps a stupid question, but have you verified that `Twitterstorians_hashtag` was retrieved correctly and does not contain any errors or malformation within its structure?

Comment: From looking at the Twitterstorians_hashtag, everything looks correct. I can view the df in RStudio and everything looks structured right. I just can't write it to a CSV.